# Issue with recursive CTE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

This query generates the numbers from 1 to 4.

```
with recursive z(q) as (
  select 1
  union all
  select q + 1 from z where q < 4
  )
select * from z;
```

But, if I modify it to this,

```
with x as (
  select 1 y
  ),
recursive z(q) as (
  select y from x
  union all
  select q + 1 from z where q < 4
  )
select * from z;
```

It gives

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "z"

What did i do wrong here?

Comment: Later related answer with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35249370/939860

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because [RECURSIVE is modifier of WITH statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), not a property of common table expression `z`, so you can use it like this:

```
with recursive
x as (
  select 1 y
),
z(q) as (
  select y from x
  union all
  select q + 1 from z where q < 4
)
select * from z;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1940)</kbd>**

Comment: Recursive enables self-referencing queries in any of the list of multiple CTEs, not just the first.