# How to use multiple CTEs in a single SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

Is it possible to combine multiple CTEs in single query?

I am looking for way to get result like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
...
),
WITH RECURSIVE cte2 AS (
...
),
WITH cte3 AS (
...
)
SELECT ... FROM cte3 WHERE ...
```

As you can see, I have one recursive CTE and two non recursive.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Use the key word `WITH` *once* at the top. If any of your Common Table Expressions (CTE) are recursive (rCTE) you have to add the keyword `RECURSIVE` at the top *once* also, even if not all CTEs are recursive:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
  cte1 AS (...)         -- can still be non-recursive
, cte2 AS (SELECT ...
           UNION ALL
           SELECT ...)  -- recursive term
, cte3 AS (...)
SELECT ... FROM cte3 WHERE ...
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH)

> If `RECURSIVE` is specified, it **allows** a `SELECT` subquery to
> reference itself by name.

Bold emphasis mine. And, even more insightful:

> **Another effect of `RECURSIVE` is that `WITH` queries need not be ordered**:
> a query can reference another one that is later in the list. (However,
> circular references, or mutual recursion, are not implemented.)
> Without `RECURSIVE`, `WITH` queries can only reference sibling `WITH`
> queries that are earlier in the `WITH` list.

Bold emphasis mine again. Meaning that the order of `WITH` clauses is *meaningless* when the `RECURSIVE` key word has been used.

BTW, since `cte1` and `cte2` in the example are not referenced in the outer `SELECT` and are plain `SELECT` commands themselves (no collateral effects), they are never executed (unless referenced in `cte3`).

Comment: Erwin Trendsetter laying down that CTE knowledge. +1 - thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 82):

Yes.  You don't repeat the `WITH`.  You just use a comma:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
...
),
     cte2 AS (
...
),
     cte3 AS (
...
)
SELECT ... FROM 'cte3' WHERE ...
```

And:  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases.  They are not allowed for CTE names anyway.

Comment: But if I need one recursive CTE with 2 non recursive?

Comment: But cte1, cte2, cte3 cannot refer to each-other, correct?

Comment: @thadk . . . They can, there is no limitation on that, other than the CTEs need to be defined before they are used.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get it to work when I tried to refer to cte1 within cte2, but I may have made a typo or something.

Answer (score 6):

As the accepted answer correctly says, the `with` clause is used only once per a CTE chain. However, for sake of completeness, I would like to add *it does not stop you from nesting CTEs*.

If `cte2` uses `cte1`, `cte3` uses `cte2` etc., then the dependency chain between CTEs is linear and it is expressed as `with` with 3 CTEs. On the contrary, if `cte2` doesn't need `cte1` and both are needed only in `cte3` it should be considered to nest them under definition of `cte3` (`with cte3 as (with cte1 as (...), cte2 as (...) select...)`).

The syntax of CTEs then reflects the dependency tree between CTEs and literally visualizes the scope of partial datasets which can improve readability and prevents scope leakage bugs. Not all db vendors support it but Postgres does.

[Example:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=05f403cf516852b4ef416aeeb9df6aa3)

```sql
with cte1(id,capital) as (
  values(1,'Prague'),(2,'Bratislava')
), cte2(id,code) as (
  with cte2inner1(id,code) as (
    values(1,'CZ'),(2,'SK')
  ), cte2inner2(id,country) as (
    values(1,'Czech Republic'),(2,'Slovakia')
  )
  select id,country from cte2inner1 join cte2inner2 using (id)
) 
select *
from cte1 join cte2 using (id)
--join cte2inner1  not possible here
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem Reason: Here, you don't have to use multiple WITH clause for combine Multiple CTE.

Solution: It is possible to create the Multiple Common Table Expression's using single WITH clause in SQL. The two different CTE's are created using Single WITH Clause and this is separated by comma to create multiple CTE's.

Sample Multiple CTE's using single

```
With EmpCount1(DeptName,TotalEmployees)
as
  (
   Select DeptName, COUNT(*) as TotalEmployees
   from Tbl_EmpDetails
   join Tbl_Dept Dept
   on Tbl_EmpDetails.DeptId = Dept.DeptId
   WHERE DeptName IN ('BI','DOTNET')
   group by DeptName
  ),
EmpCount2(DeptName,TotalEmployees)
as
  (
   Select DeptName, COUNT(*) as TotalEmployees
   from Tbl_EmpDetails
   join Tbl_Dept Dept
   on Tbl_EmpDetails.DeptId = Dept.DeptId
   WHERE DeptName IN ('JAVA','AI')
   group by DeptName
  )


  Select * from EmpCount1
  UNION
  Select * from EmpCount2
```

This is sample syntax for creating multiple Common Table Expression's with a single With Clause.