# Join a CTE to a main query

Tags: sql-server

How to I join a CTE to a main query?

(ps: Thank you again - this community is brilliant)

```
 With tempCTE1locws ([1stchargeableweights], movementref, lastdate)
as 
(Select  
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS [1stchargeableweights], 
mm.MovementRef [movementref], 
MAX (ts.systemstamp) [lastdate]

FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
AND c.[Service Type] = 'F'
AND ts.SlackNoSlack = 'slack' 
or ts.slacknoslack like 'slack - tripped%'
WHERE wh.ArrDepDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP by mm.MovementRef),
```

I would like to join this CTE to dbo.movmovement on movementref. However, writing it like

```
From dbo.movmovement m 
Inner join dbo.tempCTE1locws locws on locws.movementref = m.movementref
```

doesn't work at all.

Comment: Remove the comma at the end, then use the CTE name as a table. e.g. SELECT * FROM dbo.movmovement AS m INNER JOIN tempCTE1locws AS locws ........ you only get a single use from the CTE though.

Comment: Hi @DaveBrown, thank you for your answer! Following the tempCTE1locws I have another CTE: tempCTE1locwns ([1stchargeableweightns], movementref, lastdate). By deleting the comma at the end, it affects the following CTE. How do I go around this? Thank you again

Comment: When you say doesn't work at all? What happens?An error?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Incorrect syntax near 'tempCTE1locwns'. that is the error I am getting - it is the next CTE that I am trying to create. If I add the comma then the error disappears, but the inner join still doesn't work on the basis that tempCTE1locws is an invalid object name.

Comment: Hi - suggested the removal of the comma because that's all the code you posted :) If you have following CTE's, yes the comma is required. See if you can resolve it given the information from @DhruvJoshi. If not, post the entire code and I'll see if I (or anyone else) can assist. Without all the code, we can't know if it's just because you've "consumed" the CTE once and are trying to do it a second time, or if it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

So there's an excellent SO answer on this topic that you should go through.
[Multiple CTE in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248217/multiple-cte-in-single-query)

Quoting from accepted answer

> Use the key word WITH once at the top and if any of your Common Table
>   Expressions (CTE) are recursive (rCTE) you have to add the keyword
>   RECURSIVE at the top also, even if not all CTEs are recursive:
>
> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
>   cte1 AS (...)  -- can still be non-recursive
> , cte2 AS (SELECT ...
>            UNION ALL
>            SELECT ...)  -- recursive term
> , cte3 AS (...)
>
> SELECT ... FROM cte3 WHERE ...
> ```

This is the reason why you need , in CTE definition.

Your error is coming up because you have a typo.

> Incorrect syntax near 'tempCTE1locwns'. that is the error I am getting

See the extra n in CTE name; it should be `tempCTE1locwns` and not `tempCTE1locwns`

Comment: Hi @DhruvJoshi! It worked brilliantly :) thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @Diana Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.