# Using nested query twice within one query - for FROM and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, in-subquery

I am trying to figure out why the following Microsoft SQL code does not work. I simplified the query as it is quite complex. Basically the part that is not working is the second nested subquery (line FROM a) - I get an error: Invalid object name 'a'.

I would appreciate any advice on why it is not working and how I could make it work. Some background sources on why is it not working would also be helpful, as I struggle to find any information on limitations of nested queries beyond some basics.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT ... FROM ...
) a

WHERE x IN( 
SELECT x 
FROM a  
WHERE v1=v2)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want a cte?

Comment: It appears at though the error would be resulting from the second to last line in your pseudo query as the `a` in question is an alias for the first subquery. Can you provide any sample date and code so working alongside to debug would be more effective?

Comment: thanks @jarlh, I just looked up what ctes are and I managed to rewrite my code using cte so that it works.

Unfortunately I am not able to provide sample date as the data I work on is private sensitive data. But the problem is solved, thanks!

Comment: You have more information here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248217/multiple-cte-in-single-query

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem thanks to the suggestion in the comments to use CTE.
So I transformed it into:

```
WITH CTE_1
AS
 (
SELECT ... FROM ...
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE_1
WHERE x IN( 
SELECT x 
FROM CTE_1  
WHERE v1=v2)
```